# Is there a length limit for the ActiveDirectory member attribute?

Tags: java, active-directory

I would like to know if there is a length limit on the `member` attribute of a group in Active Directory and how to control this when doing queries through Java.

I am asking, because I am querying a group which has nested groups. A company-based tool is reporting the group Y is a member of X. I wrote an application which successfully lists all the `member` attributes of groups and in iterates through them transitively in order to illustrate things. However, it's not finding a particular groups which the other tool is reporting as a `member` and I am trying to figure out the reason. A colleague said he remembers coming across a limit of 1024 chars for the `member` property. I am using the standard `javax` packages from the `1.7.0_45` Java SDK.

Just to clarify: the `member` attribute contains a very long list of users and groups.

Answer (score 1):

All Active Directory attributes are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For the specific [member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute it seems they don't have a `size` limit.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about more than 1500 members?  Or more than 1000 if it's a Windows 2000 domain controller?  If so, you need to do Range Retrieval.  I don't know Java but I did find this, which contains sample code: [JNDI, Active Directory, Paging and Range Retrieval](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1157644).